# Linux Distrib with build in Web filter solution

Tags: distribution-choice, webserver, filter

Is there any distribution with a built in solution for web content filtering for my network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu has Squid in it's repository which is easy to configure. I do believe other distros have it as well.

https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/squid.html

Answer (score 0):

Sme server has an easy enough module with Web management.

http://wiki.contribs.org/WebFiltering